Working remotely for German company, with german residency
I'm looking for new work where Employer allows me to work remotely outside germany (Dubai) for extended periods.
Based on my research, a new regulation exception went into force  on July 2023, which allow employee to remain under the social security system if worked remotely for less than 50% (not 25% as earlier).
Please correct me if I'm wrong, and whzt other limitation / regulations I need to consider ?
n.b: I hold blue card now (tied to work category not employee), not sure; this makes much difference
